# How to call custom data loader on Spring application start

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-roo

I'm trying to load some data to my DB on application start. I have a bean defined for this purpose

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="com.project.loader.DataLoader" 
id="DataLoader" 
depends-on="entityManagerFactory" 
scope="singleton"/>
```

class:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooConfigurable
public class DataLoader implements InitializingBean
```

It is being executed however on first persist() method being call, Spring throws me following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)
at com.project.lib.model.extensions.i18n.Locale_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.entityManager_aroundBody0(Locale_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:19)
at com.project.lib.model.extensions.i18n.Locale_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$com_project_lib_model_extensions_i18n_Locale_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$com_project_lib_model_extensions_i18n_Locale$entityManager(Locale_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:1)
at com.project.lib.model.extensions.i18n.Locale.entityManager(Locale.java:1)
```

Previousely it was working when I defined DataLoader in following way:

```
@Component
@Configurable
public class DataLoader implements ApplicationListener
```

but using raw types is not good practice so I would like to switch

How can I make it work?

Spring version: 3.1

Comment: Do you think removing @Component is significant?

Comment: In my current implementation (top one) Component is removed and bean is defined in applicationContext. It was working with @Component and IoC scanning however problem is in bad practice of using raw type ApplicationListener interface.

Bean method is being called by too early I think...

Comment: If raw types are all you're worried about, why not just use `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` or something similar?

Comment: ...on top of it I would like to have something I can control order of execution. Dependency on other beans would work for me however dependency on entityManagerFactory is not enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue in the past by moving the component-scan definition to the end of the application context, as suggested [here](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-84312.html)

Comment: It is not exactly what I'm looking for. You use ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> which makes class being called couple of times. I will stick to this if no better solution found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use the spring SmartLifecycle:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html

I've created a class that does this nicely, just extend and override the run method:

```
public abstract class StartupService implements SmartLifecycle {
/** Logger for this class and subclasses */
protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupService.class);

protected boolean running=false;

////////////////////// Lifecycle Methods \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
@Override
public void start() {
    try {
        logger.info("starting {}", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("failed to run importer", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    running=false;
}

@Override
public boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
}

////////////////////// SmartLifecycle Methods \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
@Override
public boolean isAutoStartup() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void stop(Runnable callback) {
    stop();
    callback.run();
}

@Override
public int getPhase() {
    return 0;
}

public abstract void run() throws Exception;
}
```